# How can I efficiently check whether two arrays reduce to the same set?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, set, unique

What is the most efficient way to compare two arrays to see if it contains the same elements considering only the distinct elements? Assume that both array are of the same length.
What would be the pseudocode for such an algorithm. By distinct elements I mean for example S1 = {1,2,2,3} and S2 = {1,1,2,3} are equals

Comment: What do you mean by "considering only the distinct elements"? Be more specific. What you can do (under the assumption that the arrays can indeed be sorted) is to sort both arrays and remove duplicate elements (complexity: `n*log(n)`), then scan through both arrays and compare corresponding elements (complexity: `n`). The overall complexity is `n*log(n)`.

Comment: How do I remove duplicate elements? What would be the algorithm with complexity of n

Comment: *How do remove duplicate elements?* What do you mean by that? The answer to this question is likely to language-specific...

Comment: What's the point of this question, given that you've omitted a specific language? Is there an actual problem you're trying to solve, or is this some form of theoretical computer-science research?

Comment: More towards algorithm understanding. So language doesn't really matter

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays are sorted, then comparing their contents is pretty efficient (basically scanning through them).

*Update*: Start at the *low* end of each array, and repeat the following: If the two current elements are different, or one array is exhausted before the other, stop (the arrays are different).  Otherwise, skip over all copies of the current value in both arrays.  Once you have exhausted both arrays, you know they are equals (by your definition).

```
i = j = 0
while i < length(S1) and j < length(S2) do
    if S1[i] != S2[j]
        return false
    val = S1[i]
    while i < length(S1) and S1[i] == val do
        increment i
    while j < length(S2) and S2[j] == val do
        increment j
return (i == length(S1) and j == length(S2))
```

Comment: But there is a problem. Since I am only considering the distinct elements, a direct comparison won't do. Say for example Array1 = {5,5,5,6,7} and Array2 = {5,5,6,7,7}

Comment: Until you detail just what kind of comparison you need, I can't give any more details about how the scanning would work.

Comment: Like comparing two mathematical sets. You only look at the elements that are distinct from both sets and compare them. If they contain the same distinct elements, then they are equal regardless of their number of occurrences within the set

Comment: Would you mind writing a pseudocode for it because I dont really know how to implement it in code

Comment: Thank you. Your pseudocode made me understand the code implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is pseudocode (readable and short) by itself.
So here is all the code you need.
uniq means: sort the array, filter out the double values
and compare the contents.
As you can see in the example, you can even use nested arrays.

```
s1 = [1,2,2,3]
s2 = [1,1,2,3]
s3 = [1,2,3,1]
s4 = [0,1]
s5 = [1,2,[2,2],3]

print s3.uniq #[1, 2, 3]
print s1.uniq == s2.uniq #true
print s1.uniq == s3.uniq #true
print s1.uniq == s4.uniq #false
print s1.flatten.uniq == s5.flatten.uniq #true
```